A ResourceDictionary in a referenced assembly is loaded in design, but can't be found in runtime
I have a WPF application (WPFTester.exe) in which I want to use a style dictionay defined in another assembly (ABRevitAddInManager.dll).
When I reference the assembly in 'App.xaml' and try to use the style in a window everything works fine while in the designer.
However when I try to run the program a runtime error occurs stating that the referenced assembly cannot be found.
This is what the 'App.xaml' looks like:
<Application x:Class="WPFTester.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTester"
             StartupUri="WPF/Views/MainView.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ABRevitAddInManager;component/WPF/ABStyleDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

And here the code that I use in my window class:
<Window x:Class="WPFTester.WPF.Views.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTester.WPF.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource Red Button}"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Resulting in the following window in the designer (as expected):
MainWindow
